# Using Model.create() and save() inside for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Hey so I'm pretty new to Javascript and Node but I'm running into an issue that's been bothering me for a while.

I have a User model and an Image model, I'm using Multer to upload an array of images and ***trying to loop through this array, create a new Image model for each, then unshift that Image into my User's photos***. I have Multer set up to successfully fills req.files. Here's the code.

```
router.post("/users/:user/photos/upload", middle.isLoggedIn, upload.array("photos", 4), function(req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.user, function(err, foundUser) {
        for(var i = 0, len = req.files.length; i < len; i++) {
            Image.create(req.files[i], function(err, newImage) {
                if(err) {
                    return console.log(err.message);
                }
                newImage.human = foundUser;
                newImage.save();
                console.log(newImage);
                foundUser.photos.unshift(newImage);
                foundUser.save();
            });
        }
        console.log(foundUser);
    });
});
```

`console.log(foundUser);` seems to execute and print before `console.log(newImage);`

User Model

```
var mongoose                = require("mongoose"),
    passportLocalMongoose   = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    city: String,
    photos: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Image"
        }    
    ]
});

HumanSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Image Model

```
var mongoose            = require("mongoose");

var ImageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fieldname: String,
    originalname: String,
    mimetype: String,
    filename: String,
    destination: String,
    size: Number,
    path: String,
    human: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Human"
        }
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Image", ImageSchema);
```

This is my first stackoverflow question so let me know if I didn't post enough code.

I think it have something to do with Image.create() being asynchronous, and I'm still trying to learn more about this and promises, but I still don't fully understand how it's relevant in my code.

Comment: I don't see where in your code `console.log(req.user);` occurs. Do you mean `console.log(foundUser);`?

Comment: Yeah @dave sorry, edited original post

Answer (score 1):

Use [Mongoose's promise support](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) allows you to resolve an array of promises.

[`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) control flow for Promises.

I'm not sure your code as it is structured will work without a serial loop due the async code that can execute in any order. I'm not sure that triggering multiple `foundUser.save()`s on the same object at different times will work out very well. Holding database objects in memory for a long time can open up more concurrency data issues too.

The [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) promise library includes some additional helpers like [`Promise.each`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html) which will serially complete promises before the next starts which may be of use here.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')

router.post("/users/:user/photos/upload", middle.isLoggedIn, upload.array("photos", 4), async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        let foundUser = await User.findById(req.params.user)
        await Promise.each(req.files, async file => {
            let newImage = await Image.create(file)
            newImage.human = foundUser;
            await newImage.save()
            console.log(newImage)
            foundUser.photos.unshift(newImage)
            await foundUser.save()
        }
        console.log(foundUser)
    }
    catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
})
```

Other methods like [`.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) and [`.reduce`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.reduce.html) help make standard array/loop type operations with Promises easier to do.

**Atomic Updates**

In regards to the concurrency issue, any updates you can do in MongoDB that are "atomic" are a good thing. So instead of selecting something, modifying it in JS, then saving it back, you send the update to Mongo and let the db server deal with it. No matter what order you send the updates to the database, they will always be updating the latest copy of data.

In this case the array `unshift` can be completed without the initial select by using [`findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) and [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) (it can be made to push at position 0, there is no `$unshift` in mongo).

If you add a method to your User model for the adding the photo:

```
addPhoto(user_id, newImage){
    return User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        user_id,
        { $push: { photos: { $each: [newImage], $position: 0 } } } }
        { safe: true, new: true }
    )
}
```

So the code would look like

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')

router.post("/users/:user/photos/upload", middle.isLoggedIn, upload.array("photos", 4), async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        let foundUser = await User.findById(req.params.user)
        if (!foundUser) throw new Error(`No user found: $user`)
        let results = await Promise.map(req.files, async file => {
            let newImage = await Image.create(file)
            newImage.human = foundUser
            await newImage.save()
            console.log(newImage)
            let user_update = await User.addPhoto(req.params.user, newImage)
            console.log(user_update)
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
})
```